# How to open a modal referencing a menu id

Tags: jquery, wordpress

The following code works fine in opening a modal window with an html page inside.

```
<a href="http://myUrl.com/testpage.html" 
   onclick="$(this).modal({width:600, height:400}).open(); return false;">Menu Modal Window</a>
```

I have a Wordpress menu selection I want to reference to open the Modal. This is what the link looks like:

```
    <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-51"><a href="http://myUrl.com/testpage.html">Menu Modal Window</a></li>
```

I am not able to edit the menu code and add the onClick event as you see above, so I have added the following jQuery:

```
$('#menu-item-51').click(function() {
    $(this).modal({width:600, height:400}).open();
    return false;
});
```

This does not open the Modal but instead forwards to the testpage.html. I think my problem is with my reference to "this" in the jQuery. Not sure how to solve this problem...? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like you want to target anchor instead of your list:

```
$('#menu-item-51 a').click(function() {
    $(this).modal({width:600, height:400}).open();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Added the "a" and it still loads the page in the parent.

Comment: Eli, added the following which opened the modal with a 404 error.      $(document.getElementById('menu-item-51')).modal({width:700, height:480}).open();

Comment: Eli, not sure what I did wrong and you are absolutely correct, thank you very much.